# Создание интерфейса в Java

Tags: java, интерфейс

Возник вопрос, который связан с созданием интерфейса.

**Задание** стоит так: создать собственный интерфейс с одним методом и реализовать его, и внутрений класс внутри этого метода, который будет возвращать указатель на данный интерфейс. 
Извините за глупость вопроса, но что надо сделать? Ведь насколько я знаю интерфейс - это класс с методами, которые не описываються в нем? Если да, то как понять "будет возвращать указатель на данный интерфейс"?

Если можно с примером, пожалуйста.

Comment: А почему вы спрашиваете тут? Спросите это у того, кто дал задание.

Comment: Речь о Java 7 или Java 8?

Comment: @Nofate мне даже напомнило мой вопрос)) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491171/java-8-interface-%D0%B8-abstract-class .......... так что, Muscled Boy  если это java8 - то там можно всё)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, Как Вас понять "можно все"?

Comment: @MuscledBoy, это значит - можно то, что в Java 7 было нельзя )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Java 8 появились `default`-методы в интерфейсах, и можно провернуть такое:

```
interface Foo {                      // интерфейс

    default Foo foo() {              // его метод foo с реализацией по-умолчанию, который должен вернуть экземпляр интерфейса
        class Bar {                  // локальный класс Bar в методе foo
            public Foo bar() {       // метод bar класса Bar
                return new Foo() {   // возвращаем экземпляр анонимной реализацию интерфейса

                };
            }
        }

        return new Bar().bar();      // создаем экземпляр локального класса Bar, вызываем метод bar и возвращаем то, что он вернул 
    }
}

public class Baz implements Foo {             // класс Baz, унаследованный от Foo (а значит у него есть метод foo)

    public static void main(String[] args) {  // отсюда стартует программа
        Baz myBaz = new Baz();                // создаем экземпляр класса Baz  
        Foo myFoo = myBaz.foo();              // вызываем на нем метод foo ,который вернет нам анонимный экземпляр Foo, созданный методом bar класса Bar
    }                        
}
```

---

Комментарии:

> зачем Вы ставите перед методами `bar` и `foo` "Foo"?

Это тип возвращаемого значения. Любой метод должен либо что-то возвращать, либо быть `void`.

> а последняя строка это по сути создание экземпляра "Foo" - "myFoo"?

Да, именно так.

> создать интерфейс с одним методом и реализовать его, это что? в данном случае его реализация - это создание локального класса и возвращение его экземпляра? или под "реализовать" его подразумевается интерфейс, а это делает класс "Baz"?

Создать интерфейс с одним методом - это объявление `interface Foo` и `Foo foo()`.
Реализовать его можно либо в конкретном классе (`Baz`), либо в `default`-методе в самом интерфейсе.
В данном случае его реализация - это реализация по-умолчанию в методе `default Foo foo()`.
Класс `Baz`, реализующий интерфейс `Foo` благодаря наличию у метода `foo()` реализации по-умолчанию, нужен чтобы можно было создать какой-то объект, у которого можно позвать метод `foo()`.

Comment: речь шла о 8 java

Comment: могу ли Вас попросить объяснить код, чесно говоря, немного запутался.

Comment: и что Вы хотели сказать говоря "можно провернуть такое", я только начинающий, поэтому не судите строго за глупость и, возможно, излишнюю простоту вопроса

Comment: Фразой "можно провернуть такое" я имел в виду, что приведенный код работоспособен.

Comment: а что такое анонимная реализация?

Comment: И спасибо за Ваши коментарии, буду разбираться

Comment: Анонимная, значит мы не создаем отдельный именованный класс.

Comment: @MuscledBoy, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, так стало ясно. Последний вопрос: в самом начале Вы спросили о каком java идет речь, я прочитал теорию, но не совсем понял в чем суть "дефолтного" метода в интерфейсе. Могли бы Вы объяснить?

Comment: А ведь те "Foo" точно были типами методов, как-то вылетело из головы.

Comment: Суть как раз в том, что мы в интерфейсе можем задать реализацию метода. И класс, реализующий интерфейс, может уже не определять этот метод, если это не требуется.