# Может ли интерфейс в java иметь не абстрактные методы?

Tags: java, методы, интерфейс, итераторы

Раньше, на вопрос о том "что такое интерфейс" я отвечал "полностью абстрактный класс", то есть класс, все методы которого абстрактны (не имеют тела), но недавно начал разбираться с итератором и вдруг выяснилось, что у 2 его методов тело есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем ситуация не очень понятная

Comment: да, с некоторых пор (Java 8) может быть реализация (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491171/191482 - краткий вопрос

Comment: Код нужно вставлять в вопросы текстом, а не скриншотами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) сказано что методы по умолчанию добавлены чтобы производитель интерфейса мог его расширять задним числом не принуждая потребителей переписывать код, добавляя ненужные им реализации повсюду.

> Default methods enable you to add new functionality to the interfaces
> of your libraries and ensure binary compatibility with code written
> for older versions of those interfaces.

Выглядит как заплатка.

Например, вы, автор библиотеки, написали интерфейс:

```
public interface I {
    void f();
}
```

Пользователь использовал ваш интерфейс:

```
public class Usage implements I {
    public void f() {
    }
}
```

Позже вы расширили интерфейс новой функциональностью:

```
public interface I {
    void f();
    void g();
}
```

Пользователь обновил библиотеку и получил ошибку при компиляции:

> ```
> Usage.java:1: error: Usage is not abstract and does not override abstract method g() in I
> ```

Сломана обратная совместимость, что плохо: вы один, пользователей много.

Залатаем дыру:

```
public interface I {
    void f();
    default void g() {
    }
}
```

Все довольны: вы расширили интерфейс, а пользователи не должны писать новый код.