# Статические методы в интерфейсах java

Tags: java

Вот к примеру, методы default были введены с целью расширения возможностей интерфейса. Так как добавление обычных методов нарушило бы работоспособность всех программ имплементирующих этот интерфейс. Поэтому, default-методы - некий костыль, для решения этой задачи. Но вот смысл внедрения статических методов мне не ясен. Другими словами, какая была необходимость их внедрения в интерфейс java.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/491171/191482   похоже?

Comment: Что-то я не увидел там упоминания статических методов.

Comment: А какая разница, статика не статика, суть от этого не изменилась

Comment: Хорошо, и в чем же суть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похожий вопрос на основном СО: [What is the purpose of a static method in interface from Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780952/)

Основные причины добавления статических методов:

1. Статические методы являются частью интерфейса и не могут переопределяться в классах-реализациях -- это улучшает безопасность кода
2. Статические методы -- удобная замена для утилитных (вспомогательных) методов (например, проверки на `null`, сортировки и т.д.) и утилитных классов типа `Collections`
3. При помощи статических методов удобно создавать *экземпляры* соответствующих интерфейсов, например, [`Predicate.isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#isEqual-java.lang.Object-), [`Predicate.not` (Java 11)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)), [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) и т.д.

Дополнительные ссылки:

- Хабр: [История эволюции интерфейсов в Java](https://habr.com/ru/post/482498/)
- Digital Ocean: [Java 8 Interface Changes - static method, default method](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-8-interface-changes-static-method-default-method)

Comment: Спасибо! После анализа интерфейса Collection и его служебного класса - Collections, появилось понимание темы статических методов (надеюсь, что понимание правильное).